# Cannot do inner join on an select, invalid in the select list

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a stored proceedure that builds a temporary table and executes a select on the end. It works fine as long as I don't include the l.beskrivning which is a table that maps country codes to country names. The proceedure is valid but when I test it I get the following error:

> Column 'LK.b' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT TOP 100 tmp.BuyerID, tmp.BuyerNumber, tmp.BuyerName, tmp.BuyerAddress, tmp.BuyerCountryCode, l.b
    FROM #tempGL AS tmp
    INNER JOIN LK AS l ON l.land_id LIKE tmp.BuyerCountryCode
    GROUP BY tmp.BuyerID, tmp.BuyerNumber, tmp.BuyerName, tmp.BuyerAddress, tmp.BuyerCountryCode
    ORDER BY Count(*) DESC, tmp.BuyerName
```

I've also tried removing the GROUP BY and ORDER BY completely but I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Select TOP *` is not MySQL syntax! Retag with correct RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `l.beskrivning` in `group by` clause

```
SELECT TOP 100 tmp.BuyerID, tmp.BuyerNumber, tmp.BuyerName, tmp.BuyerAddress, tmp.BuyerCountryCode, l.beskrivning
    FROM #tempGL AS tmp
    INNER JOIN LK AS l ON l.land_id LIKE tmp.BuyerCountryCode
    GROUP BY tmp.BuyerID, tmp.BuyerNumber, tmp.BuyerName, tmp.BuyerAddress, tmp.BuyerCountryCode,l.beskrivning
    ORDER BY Count(*) DESC, tmp.BuyerName
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem! Would never have found it!

Answer (score 0):

What part of the error message do you not understand?  All columns not being aggregated should be in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT TOP 100 t.BuyerID, t.BuyerNumber, t.BuyerName, tmp.BuyerAddress, t.BuyerCountryCode, l.beskrivning
FROM #tempGL t INNER JOIN
     LK l
     ON l.land_id LIKE t.BuyerCountryCode
GROUP BY t.BuyerID, t.BuyerNumber, t.BuyerName, t.BuyerAddress, t.BuyerCountryCode, l.beskrivning
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC, t.BuyerName
```